# Calling a second uitableview from a uisplitview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisplitview

Im new to IOS programming but doing a bit for practice.
I've created this uisplit view fixed my cells up etc...etc...
but what im trying to do is drill down to a  my second uitable of the splitview.
Althought i think i did everything correctly...when i click the cell to go to the next tableview 
the Uitableview loads and also gives me a back button but the cells is blank as if my array code didnt populate it
im trying my best not to use interface builder and do it all programmatically.

This is an uploaded copy of my project if anyone wants to look at it.
Thanks 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/zxt9b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy of the project at that link doesn't contain any code in `SecondView` that would display any cells but I think your bigger problem is that you create two different `SecondView` objects.  One of them is created in the app delegate and given the `species` data, while the other is created when a cell is tapped in `LeftViewController` and pushed.

Storing instance information in one object of a particular type doesn't make it available to other objects just because they're the same type.

Comment: ok, thanks...i saw the error i was not adding the code to display the cells under the comment //configure the cell... 

so i added 
specie *Specie=[_species objectAtIndex:indexPath.row
cell.textLabel.text=Specie.name;
return cell;

 but it still shows me nothing.
Also concerning the "Bigger problem" ...I dont know what to do because...in app Delegate i populate the array and in Leftview i call it when the row is pushed...where should i delete it from

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the point that they are two **different** objects.  Either create one in the app delegate and pass it to the view controller to use or create it in the view controller when you need it.  One way or the other, make sure that the object that is given the array is the same object that you ask to display it.

Comment: ohh...ok so basically the one i created in app delegate has the names but the one i created doesnt...ok...gonna take a wack at this again